# (geo nodes ) Have multiple concentric rings move as one relative to a bigger ring

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

sorry for the vague title, I don't know myself exactly what I'm looking for.
[image]

So I have this setup from this video of ryan king https://youtu.be/H_Ipk9yLXl0 but i want to make the rings move with geo nodes instead of keyframes. In this setup the first rotate instance rotates the outer ring, and everything moves with it since not in local space which is great.

But the second rotate instance which i want to use to rotate the second ring makes every inner ring rotate on it's own axis, not the rings as a whole. Is there a way i could make that happen? (and then ring 2-1+sphere move relative to ring 3, ring 1+sphere move relative to sphere and finally sphere move relative to ring one)

I have tried to separate geometry have the same problem, I don't know if I don't know of a node that could do that or if it's just not possible.

Thanks in advance

edit: I have played a bit and got a setup like this, I thought the capture attribute would give me the rotation of the first ring and apply it to the second, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested I got an answer on blenderartist, this is what they gave me.

Start from the outer ring - rotate everything, then rotate everything except 4th ring and so on. Some rings should be rotated on X axis (it depends on where the holder is located).
I’m storing the same attribute for all objects to sort them easier.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way (some kind of bones parenting in gn).

[image]

Iterate over the collection of ordered rings and sphere (outer ring first and sphere last: name them appropriately to obtain this order).

Use a mesh as guide, indicating each rings/sphere orientation axis, from the outer ring to the sphere.

Sample these axis accordingly to each instance index in the collection of the elements to rotate.

Iterate over each, transmiting at each loop the previous calculated rotation (in local space).

The guide mesh is as follow:

[image]

as we want Y, Y, X, X and Y as axis (axis length can drive the rotation speed).

The ordered instances:

[image]

[image]

[image] (Blender 4.0)